# Are there maths articles that only need basic Calculus knowledge to be read??

Tags: soft-question

I am a high school teacher with previous experience of maths research. I would like to organize a club for my talented 11th/12th grade students where we would go through some interesting and accessible maths papers.

I would like to find maths articles that use the tools that 11th/12th grade students focus on: Calculus.

If anyone has an idea, please let me know!

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: There are journals on recreational mathematics, presumably some of the articles there are relatively accessible.

Comment: It might be worth while reading through "Proofs from the book."

Comment: How about [the shortest paper ever published](https://www.fermatslibrary.com/s/shortest-paper-ever-published-in-a-serious-math-journal-john-conway-alexander-soifer)? Here's another really short one [disproving a conjecture by Euler](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-06/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3.pdf). [Niven's proof of the irrationality of $\pi$](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510788) is another good one.